# Question about change in scikit-learn's IsolationForest anomaly score calculation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In sklearn's current version (v0.24)，the anomaly score is computed by the function `_compute_score_samples`,[click here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/6b4f82433dc2f219dbff7fe8fa42c10b72379be6/sklearn/ensemble/_iforest.py#L452) :

```py
def _compute_score_samples(self, X, subsample_features):
    scores = 2 ** (
        -depths
        / (len(self.estimators_)
           * _average_path_length([self.max_samples_]))
    )
    return scores
```

However, in v0.19, [click here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/ensemble/iforest.py#L279) this computation was different:

```py
# https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/ensemble/iforest.py
scores = 2 ** (-depths.mean(axis=1) / _average_path_length(self.max_samples_))
```

Now, the question is: why does sklearn v0.24 compute `depths/len(self.estimators_)`, rather than `depths.mean(axis=1)` as in v0.19?

Comment: Please provide relevant code in full, including the definition of depths, or link the source.

Comment: I have updated  in the question

Comment: It looks like this is the PR (but I don't immediately see the reason for the change):  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/13260/files